# Is it possible to use a bash script to do the liveness test in pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm currently setting up a kubernetes cluster with 3 nodes on 3 differents vm and each node is composed of 1 pod witch run the following docker image: ethereum/client-go:stable

The problem is that I want to do a health check test using a bash script (because I have to test a lot of things) but I don't understand how I can export this file to each container that are deployed with my yaml deployment file.

I've tried to add `wget` command in the yaml file to download my health check script from my github repo but it wasn't very clean from my point of view, maybe there is an other way ?

**My current deployment file:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: goerli
  name: goerli-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: goerli
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: goerli
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: ethereum/client-go:stable
          name: goerli-geth
          args: ["--goerli", "--datadir", "/test2"]
          env:
          - name: LASTBLOCK
            value: "0"
          - name: FAILCOUNTER
            value: "0"
          ports:
          - containerPort: 30303
            name: geth
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - /test/health.sh
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 100
          volumeMounts:
          - name: test
            mountPath: /test
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: test
        hostPath:
          path: /test
```

I expect to put health check script in /test/health.sh

Any ideas ?

Comment: hi ,yes its posiible to do it ,The kubelet executes  command inside the container. Exiting the check with status 0 is considered a success.

Comment: hi, your comment does not explain how I can resolve my problem... Maybe I have to change the title by "How can I use a bash script to do the liveness test in pod ?" ?

Comment: Correct me If I misunderstand, first you want to wget the file than you want to execute the files to demonstrate the liveness check ?

Comment: If yes, then we can use init Container to download the file at certain path then do the liveness check

Comment: In fact I've already tried the way with wget and it's seems very silly and then I'm searching a way to do properly the same things. Something like adding:
`copy: ./health.sh`
in my yaml file to export it into all pod I create

Comment: As, the sequence of the tasks are important for whole situation, then init Container is the correct solution

Comment: I assume, you mean to add it inside the docker image, then it would be hardcore solution, we could lose the flexibility. If it is just a Script file we can embedded it inside the ConfigMap and mount it at certain path

Comment: Ok it's seems great I will tried this now thanks !

Comment: yea sure :) let me know if it worked

Comment: hum it's seems that the initContainer parameter does not apply the `wget` command...
`initContainers: 
      - name: healthcheck
        image: ethereum/client-go:stable
        command: ["wget", "-O", "/health.sh", "http://My-bash-script`
Sorry for the bad rendering in comment section...

Comment: let's check the logs of it `kubectl logs <pod-name> -c healthcheck`

Comment: Aaarf logs looks good but see no file... `Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (151.101.120.133:443)
health.sh            100% |********************************|  1069  0:00:00 ETA`

Comment: init container and the app container have different filesystem , you need to use emptydir to share the file inside the app container

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/     would be good start

Comment: Here is the example https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/#create-a-pod-that-has-an-init-container

Comment: yes !!! It's working ! :D Thanks a lot !

Comment: I have a similar requirement. This will resolve my problem. However what should bash script return for success and failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be a perfect usecase for the init container, As there could be different images for the init container and the Application container thus they have different file system inside the pods, therefore we need to use **Emptydir** in order to share the state.

for further detail follow the link [init-containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)

Comment: Purpose of this init Container to have the shell Script and put it into the app's file system then that shell Script file  could be used for the readiness and liveness

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Suresh Vishnoi:

A way to resolve my problem is to use init container this way:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: goerli
  name: goerli-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: goerli
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: goerli
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: ethereum/client-go:stable
          name: goerli-geth
          args: ["--goerli", "--datadir", "/test2"]
          env:
          - name: LASTBLOCK
            value: "0"
          - name: FAILCOUNTER
            value: "0"
          ports:
          - containerPort: 30303
            name: geth
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - /test/health.sh
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 100
          volumeMounts:
          - name: test
            mountPath: /test
      initContainers: 
      - name: healthcheck
        image: ethereum/client-go:stable
        command: ["wget", "-O", "/test2/health.sh", "https://My-script-bash"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: test
          mountPath: "/test"
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: test
        emptyDir: {}
```

The downloaded file will be visible in /test/health.sh

Comment: You would still have to be root to make the downloaded script executable e.g. via `chmod +x`. If you allow root at container runtime, why not do it inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using helm look at chart tests: https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_tests.md. This covers readinessProbe tho, not liveness.

For advanced liveness probe, I'd run some kind of healthcheck sidecar which does all the advanced tests continiosly via localhost, and exposes a single `/healthcheck` endpoint. Then use the endpoint in a liveness probe.